# Celery factory function vs importing celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am developing a Flask application and leveraging blueprints.  I plan to use celery task queues.
I am trying to understand the benefit or reason to use something like

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

and then doing

```
celery = make_celery(app)
```

and importing it into my tasks.py versus just importing and creating a celery instances in my tasks.py like

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
@app.task
def mytask():
```

Comment: The advantage -- which is very important if you are using blueprints -- is that you don't have to worry too much about import order and circular imports.

Comment: Are there issues with application context when you don't use the make_celery way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are writing a simple task, it is better to import celery & decorate your function.

If You are creating some complex tasks, it is better to sublcass Task. Here You will get the power of OOP. You can break your code into small blocks. That makes it easier to unit test your code.  Also if you want some custom config for all of your tasks, you can have a custom baseclass & you can inherit from it for all the tasks.

Comment: Do I need to be worried about celery and the Flask application context when simply importing celery and decorating my tasks?  Does celery need to have access to it or am I ok just doing something like `with app.context(): runtask.delay()`

Comment: i dont know about app.context, but you don't need to worry about  celery in that context.